# How can I fix joint between shoulder strap and chest strap?

Tags: backpacks, diy, repairs

In an attempt to fasten the chest strap, the plastic clip that keeps it joined to the shoulder strap came out.

Any ideas, on how I can fix this mess?

I think I should force the clip opening to open a bit wider, as much as needed to insert the cord back in it. However, I'm afraid the plastic could break.

[image: This is the broken side]

[image: This the non-broken side]

Comment: AFAIK that brand is "budget quality". If the plastic clip has come off once, it will happen again. IMO you should throw it away and buy something more robust.

Comment: @WeatherVane it sounds like in effect you're suggesting discarding the entire bag.  Replacement clips are very hard to find, and probably no better.

Comment: @ChrisH that's what I meant. I have bought that brand and found they are little better than toys.

Comment: @WeatherVane It depends on the user and the use.  Cheap stuff may be all that's available, all the user can afford, and adequate for the task.  Throwing away perfectly serviceable kit just because there's better stuff out there is terribly wasteful

Comment: If the clips pull off or break then it isn't adequate for any task.

Comment: @WeatherVane I lost the equivalent clip and half the strap in the same way on a rather nice convertible backpack/pannier, the best on the market, when the strap snagged on a train luggage rack.  Don't assume  it came off just from wearing it.  Anyway as I say in my answer, you could replace the whole strap - for zero cost if you've got as much old kit as I have

Comment: [Charlie's answer to a related question of mine](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/20229/2529) has some names for the specific part.  I didn't know them (as a native speaker with an interest in outdoor gear), but I would call the cord "piping" when it's fitted like this.

Comment: if the pack is recent, you can contact the customer service and get it fixed by Millet.

Comment: @WeatherVane  I'd guess the clip is designed to do exactly this - break away under sufficient force so that it doesn't become a strangling hazard.  Problem is that OP is putting enough force on it to override the normal clamping force.   Personally I'd replace the whole clip with a two-piece release clip like on a bike helmet, and perhaps stitch a fold into the flyends of strapping.  Probably gonna be black not colour-matched though.

Answer (score 21):

One solution, if you don't need the strap to be adjustable along the piping (vertically), is to remove the plastic clip and sew the chest strap to the shoulder strap, in the right place for you.

Any sewing machine can do that, or you can do it by hand if you don't have a machine accessible.

Answer (score 13):

Those clips do come off, and in many designs you'd be able to thread them  back on from the end.  It is possible to clip them back on though.

The way I've found works is to gently prise open *one end* of the slot by twisting a screwdriver in it.  Then slide that end over the piping, so that the piping replaces the screwdriver in the slot.  The rest of the slot will go fairly easily.

Try to avoid doing this too often - if it keeps going you might be over-tightenting the chest strap, or snagging it on things.

It's also possible to replace the strap with one that wraps round the shoulder straps, though on that pack it wouldn't stay in place without further fastening

Answer (score 4):

Press one corner of the clip against the bead (tube, piping, whatever it's called). Slide the clip smoothly down the bead while pressing firmly inward. The jaws of the clip should "ride up" the bead, spreading them apart and around. Once one corner is in place, keep sliding it smoothly down while pressing, like pulling a zipper, and the rest should follow.

This will do less damage to the clip than prying it apart, and you should be able to do it repeatedly without damage. If it came off this easily once, you'll probably need to do it repeatedly.

Answer (score 3):

Don't mess with the clip (unless to replace it entirely). Compress the piping (cord) so that is narrow enough to slide the clip on. Usually you only need to get one end/corner of the clip on and then the clip will keep the piping compressed while you slide the rest on.

Doing it towards one end (away from wherever you normally put the strap) is best since the piping may stay a little squished and you don't want to make it easier for the clip to come off. Also, the piping is usually a little tapered/compressed by sewing towards one end, so the clip may slide on there naturally anyway.

Usually you can just use your fingers to squeeze the piping, but if it's difficult try using pliers--the part right next to the edge of the pliers will also be compressed, and you can put the corner of the clip on there.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to repair all straps using metal rivets, a rivet gun and washers. Better than sewing. You can prepare a hole in the nylon strap by carefully heating a small nail in a flame from your camping stove, held in pliers, and pushing it gently through.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to change the clips. You can buy a new one starting at 1$, that's not expensive. You can try to repair it using a strap, but if you have an opportunity and you are not camping with it now, that's a bad idea. If you repair it, it will break another time, and we don't know when. If you don't want to have it broken while camping it's better to change it now. You can do that in atelier or manual by yourself.

Comment: The clip is not broken. And I'm not able to fix it. if I buy a new one I still have the issue of how I can insert it.